# trim.() method does not work(java)

Tags: java, string, trim

So i'm trying to count the characters in a String without the spaces. But somehow my trim() method doesn't cut the spaces:

```
class Test {

HashMap<Character, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();

public void encode(String text) {
    String code = text.trim();
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
        Character key = code.charAt(i);
        if (testMap.containsKey(key)) {
            testMap.put(key, testMap.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            testMap.put(key, 1);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(testMap);
    System.out.println(code);
}
```

Main method:

```
public class MyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.encode("Tessstttt faill");

}
```

}

So the output is:

```
{ =1, a=1, s=3, T=1, t=4, e=1, f=1, i=1, l=2}
Tessstttt faill
```

Where is my mistake. Thanks a lot ahead!!
(I'm not that experienced yet, so sorry in case of obvious mistake)

Comment: .trim() only trims trailing whitespace, not whitespace inside the string.

Comment: It is not that .trim() does not work; it works as intended. It is that you misunderstood what it did... trim() is not like `tr`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trim won't remove all whitespace, only the leading and trailing. To remove all whitespace, you want something like this:

```
text.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

Comment: regex gets annoying and impossible. I prefer using text.replace(char, char) unless you need more than one char, which in this case is not needed. replace still replaces all occurrences, it just can only do one char at a time

Comment: Oh gosh thank you so much. So yes it was obvious! xD Didn't pay enough attention to the workings of trim().

Comment: @Mrab Whitespace is more than just `[ ]` so.... you'd be missing out on tabs, etc.

Comment: then do the same thing with spaces, tabs, etc etc

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstood [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) it

```
Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
```

Use `replace()` instead to remove all the spaces

```
text.replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `trim()` method only removes spaces from the beginning and end of the string. The space in your test string is somewhere in the middle, though.

Maybe a better option than trimming would be an individual check for whitespace characters. The `Character` class provides a static `isWhitespace(char)` method for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Trim does not do that. Trim would do something like this

```
" hello world ".trim() > "hello world"
```

Instead, use .replace

```
" hello world ".replace(' ', '') > "helloworld"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually trim() method in java only omits leading an trailing white spaces, not in between string. 
As http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim().

So, here also this won't omit space between Tessstttt and fail.

You may use `replace()` to remove this space, like, `code = code.replace(" ", "");`